# Which of these sentences are propositions? What are the truth values of those that are propositions?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Which of these sentences are propositions? What are the truth values of those that are propositions?
 a) Boston is the capital of Massachusetts.
 b) Miami is the capital of Florida.
 c) 2 + 3 = 5.
 d) 5 + 7 = 10.
 e) x + 2 = 11.
 f ) Answer this question.
 g) Do not pass go.
 h) What time is it?
 i) There are no black flies in Maine.
 j) The moon is made of green cheese.

Comment: A proposition is a statement that can be classified as true or false.  You can look up the capitals of Massachussetts and Florida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Propositions are *a, b, c, d ,i*  and *j*. The truth values of the following are *T ,F ,T ,F ,F ,F*   respectively.

Answer (score 0):

e,f,g,h are not propositions because
e)without the value of x we can't say it is true or not
(or)it is a predicate function and predicate
functions are not propositions.
f)it is not a declarative sentence. (its command sentence)
g)it is not a declarative sentence. (its command sentence)
h)it is not a declarative sentence.(it's interrogative sentence)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).